# Interview Q: convert table login_log to last_login

Tags: mysql, logging, authentication, greatest-n-per-group

This is a question in my interviews.

In our system, every login event is logged into the **login_log** table. It mainly contains 3 columns:

- user_id
- login_time
- login_ip

We have 36,000 users now and each user has logged in about 100 times on average so there are 3,600,000 rows in this table.

Then we want to convert this table into another table, named **last_login**, and only record the latest login event of each user. It also contains 3 columns:

- user_id
- last_login_time
- last_login_ip

So there will be no more than 36,000 rows in this new table.

Candidates can solve this problem by SQLs or programming. Some candidates solved it in only one SQL.

Enjoy it!

**UPDATE**

Hint: **login_log** may have an AUTO_INCREMENT `id` as primary key. So the latest logged in event has the maximum `id`.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**  Updated answer after finding my earlier answer was not correct

```
select
    user_id
    , max(login_time) last_login_time
    , max(login_ip)   last_login_ip 
from 
    (
        select
          user_id
          , login_time 
          , max(login_ip) login_ip
        from
          login_log
        group by user_id, login_time 
    ) t -- this sub-query makes sure we have only one row for each user_id+login_time
group by user_id;
```

You can find the result in sqlFiddle.com via this [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/69f2fe/17)

Test program -- Build the table:

```
create table login_log (
  user_id int not null
  , login_time datetime not null
  , login_ip int not null 
  , index(user_id)
  , index(login_time)
);

insert into login_log
values
(1, '2017-02-17', 100)
, (1, '2017-02-15', 200)
, (2, '2017-02-17', 300)
, (2, '2017-02-14', 400)
, (2, '2017-02-17', 500);
```

We need a sub-query (`t`) here to break the tie in case
there are more than one rows for a given `user_id` PLUS `login_time`
combination.  The sub-query makes sure only a single-row
emerges from it (the one with `max(login_ip)`)

My earlier answer forgot such a corner case and hence
was incorrect.

Comment: add another login_log row (2, '2017-02-17', 500) and try again :-)

Comment: @auntyellow -- That is a good point.  I have updated my answer above.  Thanks!